# User Badges module not respecting 'change own badge assignments' permission

Tags: 7

For version 7.x-4.x-dev, users who have 'change badge assignments' permission but not 'change own badge assignments' can still view the Badges tab and edit the badges in their own user profiles in the [User Badges](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_badges) module.

I have also created an issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2765255).

**Note**: the same issue seems to exist in the 7.x-3.x version.

Comment: I found the solution and submitted a patch [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2765255#comment-11396615). Hope this helps someone. Regards, Supriya Rajgopal

Comment: Hey Supriya, curiosity about your question (and answer): in the issue you created, in comment nr 2 of it, you changed "Version" from 7.x-4.x-dev back to 7.x-3.2. Does this mean the same issue exists in 7.x-3.2 ? BTW: thank you for sharing the patch (I haven't reviewed it though ... yet).

Comment: Hi @Pierre.Vriens, feels great to get a response from you! I created this issue when I noticed it in 7.x-4.x-dev version. Then it occurred to me that it could be because of the 'dev' version and installed the 7.x-3.2 version & submitted a patch for it. So I reverted the version in the issue queue to inform that my patch is tested on 7.x-3.2 version only. Bottomline is I think this issue exists in 7.x-4.x-dev branch also.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback / explanation. But I think your last phrase in your prior comment should be about 7.x-3.2, no? Because your original question here was already about 7.x-4.x-dev. Or am I still missing something?

Comment: Oops..yes @Pierre.Vriens, since my question states 7.x-4.x-dev, I should be answer the same. Don't you think editing the question itself to 7.x-3.2 is better because I tested my submitted patch on 7.x-3.2 only?

Comment: Check "my" edit I just applied. Feel free to correct (or rollback) should you want to do so. OK?

Comment: I corrected it to 7.x-3.x from 7.x-2.x..thanks for noticing @Pierre.Vriens :)

Comment: Maybe I intentionally entered that remaining (minor) typo, to see if you'd notice?  Joke! Happy "menu badge"-ing ...